Bluetooth app not available in Xubuntu minimal 24.04
I wiped my disk and installed Xubuntu 24.04 minimal. The OS detects my bluetooth device.
$ lspci
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)

I also have the following packages installed
$ dpkg -l | grep blu | cut -d " " -f 1-3
ii  bluetooth
ii  bluez
ii  bluez-cups
ii  bluez-obexd
ii  gnome-bluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth-3-common
ii  gnome-bluetooth-sendto
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64
ii  libbluray2:amd64
ii  libgnome-bluetooth-3.0-13:amd64
ii  libgnome-bluetooth-ui-3.0-13:amd64
ii  liblua5.4-0:amd64
ii  libspa-0.2-bluetooth:amd64

bluetoothctl also identifies the interface.
$ bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...[bluetooth]# hci0 new_settings: powered bondable ssp br/edr le secure-conn wide-band-speech 
[bluetooth]# Agent registered
[bluetooth]# [CHG] Controller D4:6A:6A:6E:69:16 Pairable: yes

However, when I open the whisker menu, I don't see any Bluetooth applications. How do I start the Bluetooth UI?

I think "blueman" is what you need.

@mikewhatever That was it! Thank you very much!

As what @mikewhatever mentioned, the required package is blueman.
